# SSH private Keys

Tags: ssh, unix, find

I want to use a simple command to count the number of ssh keys in a users home folder, but would rather use the output from the /etc/passwd file as input.

The find command is easy:

```
find /home/*/.ssh* -name id_* -exec printf '.' \;| wc -c
```

But I don't want to trawl directories that are no longer in use, so ideally I want to use the output from the line below to select specific active users only:

```
awk -F  ':' '{print $6}' < /etc/passwd
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a construct similar to this:

```
for f in `awk -F  ':' '{print $6}' < /etc/passwd`
do
  find /home/*/.ssh* -name id_* -exec printf '.' \;| wc -c
done
```

Comment: Are you counting the contents of ./ssh/authorized_keys?  Those are public keys.